# Does role attribute matter?

Tags: html, attributes, roles

```
<tag role="header"></tag>
```

from what i read on the Internet the role attribute have made for a **blind** people.
if my website oriented for people who are not blind,
should i use it or not?

Answer (score 0):

The attribute describes the role(s) the current element plays in the context of the document. This can be used, for example, by applications and assistive technologies to determine the purpose of an element.